# Why are my content ratings not displaying correctly?

Tags: 2010, social

I have a SharePoint site with the "content ratings" feature enabled. This is how it displays on one of my pages with a list view:

[Valid XHTML http://paxam.co.uk/img/sp_000.png](http://paxam.co.uk/img/sp_000.png)

All's good so far, right? Except, I've actually rated each of these pieces as 1 star, after giving them the ratings they currently show.

I've looked in the `_Social` database on the machine and both `SocialRatings` and `SocialRatings_Averages` tables reflect the new rating, yet the new ratings aren't updating on the pages.

I've run all the scheduled jobs that mention "User" or "Social", and it's been like this over the weekend so everything but the monthly jobs will have run; so I'm at a loss as to what could be causing the discrepancy between what the database shows and the user's view.

I can see that the "Pages" WebPart has a "Data View Caching" option, which I do have enabled, but the timeout on this is set to 86,400 seconds (twenty four hours) and the ratings were last computed nearly five days ago.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** I've done the following since asking this question to try and make the page ratings behave:

- I've disabled the data view caching option on the control.
- I've set *all* of the timed jobs to run on a daily basis, and the two more relevant ones (`User Profile Service Application - Social Rating Synchronization Job` and `User Profile Service Application - Social Data Maintenance Job`) to run every two minutes.
- I've disabled and re-enabled the ratings feature on the site.

And still these pages are not updating their ratings.

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve this issue ? We have faced this problem and in order to resolve it we have tried to install the latest cumulative update. It seemed that it resolved the problem, but the issue has occured again.

Comment: We are facing the same problem either! Does anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

the blue stars rating is actually showing avarage rating computed according to all votes. Your personal vote is shown only in the tooltip upon hovering the stars (so you will see something like "My Rating: 1"). This tooltip changes immediatelly after your vote, but the overall avarage rating is computed once a time - according to the Social Data Maintenance Timer Job settings.

So there must be problem with your timer job. Please run it manually again and see the log. Also be sure that your portal has configured Alternate Access Mappings correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to provide this answer. As I said in the question though, the job runs and it updates the table (`SocialRatings_Averages`). Alternate access mappings are correct.